# Unable to catch exceptions when using axios.all

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, promise, axios

I am using axios.all to send few consolidated requests.

I am using `.map` to create the axios requests and pass them to axios.all.

```
 function updateCircuitTrayData(newCircuitTrays, updatedCircuitTrays, deletedCircuitTrays, config) {
        const newReqs = newCircuitTrays.map(b => axios.post(`/`, b, config));
        const modifiedReqs = updatedCircuitTrays.map(b => axios.put(`/`, b, config));
        const deleteRequests = deletedCircuitTrays.map(b => axios.delete(`/`, b, config));
      return axios.all([newReqs, modifiedReqs, deleteRequests]);
    }
    updateBrandData(newCircuitTrays, updatedCircuitTrays, deletedCircuitTrays,  config)
    .then(
        axios.spread((...response) => {
            // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
            console.log(`Data`, response);
        })
    )
    .catch(err => {
        // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
        console.log(`Err`, err);
    });
```

The API are being called. However , onError , it never comes inside catch block. Also for success calls, I am using `axios.spread`. But when I look inside `response[0]`, I see a promise, not the resolved values.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`newReqs`, `modifiedReqs` and `deleteRequests` are arrays of axios requests. According to the [docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#axios-api), you cannot pass arrays inside an array to `axios.all`.

You can, however, spread each of the inner arrays and pass the resulting flattened array to `axios.all()`:

```
return axios.all([...newReqs, ...modifiedReqs, ...deleteRequests]);
```

Comment: Cant thank more, save just enomorous effort. Thanks!